# How to use ExecutorService to implement a conditional task?

Tags: java, timer

Here is my problem:

> I have a task with a return value, I want to call the task periodically until the return value is null.

How should I do it with ExecutorService? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        private Future<?> lastExecution;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Make sure only one task is running
            if (lastExecution != null && !lastExecution.isDone()) {
                return;
            }
            //Do your task here
            Object ret = doTask();
            if (ret == null) {
                executorService.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Please check the javadoc, it may wrong

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Comment: Your answer is an insperation for me. I cannot afford to vote you up, but thank you very much.